# HTML table: rescaling browser page and NOT show scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I've this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testPage</title>   
    <style>
        table td {
            width: 50%;
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="titlebar">
      <center>
        Select option:
        <select onchange="onSelect.call(this, event)">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
        </select>   
        <script>
          function onSelect(event) {
            switch (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text) {
              case "One":
                var td = document.getElementById("one");
                td.style.borderColor = "red";
                td.style.borderWidth = "5px";
                td.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                td.style.width = "99%";   
                var td = document.getElementById("two");
                td.style.borderColor = "black";
                td.style.borderWidth = "1px";
                td.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                td.style.width = "100%";    
                break;
              case "Two":
                var td = document.getElementById("two");
                td.style.borderColor = "red";
                td.style.borderWidth = "5px";
                td.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                td.style.width = "99%";   
                var td = document.getElementById("one");
                td.style.borderColor = "black";
                td.style.borderWidth = "1px";
                td.style.borderStyle = "solid";
                td.style.width = "100%"; 
                break;
            }
          }
        </script>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div id="images">
      <table width="100%" height="100%" border=1 cellpadding=1>
        <!-- first row -->
        <tr id="row1">
          <td id="xxx">
            <div id="xxx_div" style="width:100%;height:370px"></div>
          </td>
          <td id="yyy">
            <div id="one" style="width:100%;height:370px"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- second row -->
        <tr id="row2">
          <td id="zzz">
            <div id="zzz_div" style="width:100%;height:370px"></div>
          </td>
          <td id="kkk">
            <div id="two" style="width:100%;height:370px"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>    
    <div id="bottom">
      Bottom ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

that works fine, but if I rescale my browser page you can see that scrollbars appears (I know, I'm using absolute values for div height and the problem probably is about this, but it's only to show the problem ... ).

I'd like to obtain the same behaviour at this site

http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/

where you can see that if you rescale the browser scale, no scrollbars appears and the maps (so the  tables and its contents ... ), rescale ...

Suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
td {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course, you might adapt your table size if you need to add inputs or text outside.

Just consider always occupying a total 100% of the visible area.

Comment: your solution works fine but, I've to put a `<div>` inside each `<td>` in my rows table (look at my original code )... .I've tried to use your solution but scrollbars appearing again ....

Comment: That's because you set fixed height to your divs, the addition of all those exceed the total visible height. Just remove the height to your div or change it to 100%. Always consider children elements' group size to equal 100% of their parent's size

Comment: You're right! I've tried to modify my original code with `<div id="xxx_div" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>` (for all `<div>` ...), and now all works fine